# Set server timeout for connection in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to set server timeout for whole connection. Currently, I found only option to set it per query by `maxTimeMS` function. Is there any way to do it without changing every query in project? I'm using PHP driver.

Answer (score 0):

@kkochanski!

I think the variable you are looking for could be one of these:
'wtimeoutMS' - for Write Concern Options
'connectTimeoutMS' - for Connection Options

[Here is the doc where you can read about it](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html)

Please, let me know if this answer helps you.